# Video is not show inline when using the method "playsinline"?

Tags: javascript, ios, video, phaser-framework

help, I'm adding an instructional video before the game starts, but it opens the native player, it can't play it online.

```
    video = game.add.video('space');
    video.addToWorld();
    video.unlock();
    video.play(true);
    video.playsinline(true);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You might start by correcting the title.

Comment: I general would use phaser 3, not phaser2/CE. On Phaser 3 it should work, checkout this example https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/video/play-video

Comment: btw.: which exact version of Phaser are you using

Answer (score 0):

I tested this [Phaser 2 / CE Video Demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/video/play-video) on a local server, with the [latest Phaser CE Version 2.19.1](https://phaser.io/download/release/2.19.1), and the video *plays inline* out-of-the-box on an **IPhone SE**.

So I assume **the problem is**, that you have a olderer/too old Version of Phaser CE.

**A fast/easy Solution for Phaser CE:**

- updating your phaser to version 2.19.1,
- and removing the line `video.playsinline(true);`
  *(since phaser 2.19.1 does have this method anymore)*

... should solve your problem.

> ***Side note:** And the video will not autoplay, if you try to play the video on the initial pageload. I assume the `unlock` function, should cover this, but I didn't test it.*

*(I still strongly recommend Phaser 3, as mentioned in the comments, at least for new apps/games)*